# Array issue - Angular 11 - out of memory

Tags: angular, typescript

I have encountered following issue.

It is connected with the arrays located in the variables1.service.ts file.
I have created a function which should produce an array which result is multiplication of two other arrays elements. I looked for a typescript example however I'm wondering if it's done correctly. I'm not a programmer however would like to learn... Could you check if code below is valid?

variables1.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
@Injectable({
  providedIn:'root'
})
export class Variables1Service{

  Fcomponent: number[]=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
  Scomponent: number[]=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
```

//code which creates issue - start

```
  createmulti(array1,array2){
    let array3:number[]=[];
    for (let i1 = 0; array1.length-1; i1++) {
      for (let i2 = 0; i2 < array2.length-1; i2++) {
        array3.push(array1[i1]*array2[i2]);
      }
    }
    return array3;
  }
  public Amulti = this.createmulti(this.Fcomponent,this.Scomponent);
```

//code which creates issue - end

```
  F1comp: number[]=this.Fcomponent;
  S1comp: number[]=this.Scomponent;

  shuffle(array){
    for (let i=array.length-1;i>0;i--) {
      let j=Math.floor(Math.random()*(i+1));
      [array[i],array[j]]=[array[j],array[i]];
    }
    return array;
  }

  public F1component = this.shuffle(this.F1comp);
  public S1component = this.shuffle(this.S1comp);
```

Project is successfully compiled but when I'm trying to view it in a browser: http://localhost:4200/
There is out of memory message.

What can be done to solve it? Is my code correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake was in the for loop in *createMulti*, you have no condition in the outer loop.  You needed `i1 < array1.length` you just had `array1.length-1`.

```
// for (let i1 = 0; array1.length-1; i1++) {
for (let i1 = 0; i1 < array1.length; i1++)
  for (let i2 = 0; i2 < array2.length; i2++) {
     array3.push(array1[i1]*array2[i2]);
  }
}
```

Also, by doing `i2 < array2.length - 1`, you'll omit the last element.  I changed it in the example above.

Answer (score 0):

If you want each element of an array1 multiplied by each element of array2; you can try this instead of 2 for-loops

```
let array1 = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

let array2 = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

let array3 = [];

console.log('Array Before multiplication ==>', array3);

if (array1.length === array2.length) {
  for (let i=0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    const x = array1[i] * array2[i];
    array3.push(x);
  }
}

console.log('Array after multiplication ==>', array3);
```